# php replace string from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I want to replace filename from URI. I need this replaced url on webpage.
Example:
Page url:

```
https://www.domain.com/...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/abc.php
```

My code

```
 echo $uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It returns

```
...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/abc.php
```

But I dont need "abc.php". I need like this

```
...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/
```

This should be done using php, because I will use it on my webpage. 
Please suggest me to resolve this.

Comment: your last 3 urls are the same

Comment: This can be done by .htaccess also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple, regular `explode` & `implode` to get what you want as shown by the Snippet below. [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/686469).

```
    <?php

        // ASSUMING THAT $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; RETURNS THE STRING BELOW:
        $uri    =  /*$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];*/ "...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/abc.php";
        $parts  = explode("/", $uri);
        array_pop($parts);
        $uri    = implode("/" , $parts) . "/";
        echo $uri;    //<== YIELDS::: ...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/
```

Alternatively and even preferably, You could use the `basename()` Function in combination with `str_replace()` to achieve the same goal:

```
    <?php

        // ASSUMING THAT $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; RETURNS THE STRING BELOW:
        $uri        =  /*$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];*/ "...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/abc.php";
        $baseName   =  basename($uri);
        $uri        = str_replace($baseName, "", $uri);
        echo $uri;   //<== YIELDS::: ...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/
```

In a condensed form:

```
    <?php

        $uri        =  /*$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];*/ "...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/abc.php";;
        $uri        = str_replace(basename($uri), "", $uri);
        echo $uri;   //<== YIELDS::: ...../india-hotels/dun-hotels/
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable **rewrite** module in apache.

Write this in your **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this

```
$uri_ar=array();
$uri=($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(strpos($uri,'.php')){    
  $uri_ar=explode('/',$uri);

  array_pop($uri_ar);
  $uri=implode('/',$uri_ar);

}
```